# arpspoof: fetch packets of different gateway

Tags: networking, routing, gateway

I have to test a network which have 5 different gateways. I am connected to one of the gateway and I am able to ping the other gateway in the network. It is possible to generate fake arp request using `arpspoof` for a different gateway and get packets?

For example :
My ip : 172.22.30.132,
My gateway : 172.22.30.1

Other gateways on network : 172.22.32.1 , 172.22.34.1 etc..

I can do `arpspoof -i eth0 172.22.32.1` but it won't fetch any packets. However `arpspoof -i eth0 172.22.30.1` will work.

(This is ONLY for testing purpose)

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible to generate fake arp request using arpspoof for a different gateway and get packets

i think you may be confusing things here. i am not clear if you mean

1) spoof the mac addr of the existing lan default gateway, in combination with dos'ing the real gateway, so as to become the new gateway for your private lan, effectively becoming mitm

2) injecting route specifying your ip is the best route for "whatever" network.  arp spoofing is not required for this, as it is the fundamental way routing protocols / the internet works, but you do have to be able to inject a prefered route into the layer 3 infrastructure.

if it is #1, this is commonly done with WAPs, but if you have layer 1 physical access, there is no reason you shouldnt be able to do this with ethernet (for testing purposes only).